# Create a new list withing a namedtuple variable, and iterate through it while simulation is running?

Tags: python

I have built a charging simulation program(Works perfectly!), and when I run simulation it prints out live info about what happened at a specific charging station(how many cars charging, how many are in queue etc etc.)

Now I want to save this information so I can use this for creating a CSV file, and as I noticed, there are a lot of of options here.

I am currently trying nametuples, which works fine.

Here is the code for that little piece:

```
        hotspot_record = namedtuple("hotspot_day_info", ('hour', 'name', 'cars_in_queue', 'rejected_cars', 'bailed_cars','count_queue_per_hour_and_avg'))
        hotspot_stats_per_hours.append(hotspot_record(
        hour=hour,
        name=hotspot.station_name,
        cars_in_queue=len(hotspot.cars_waiting_in_queue),
        rejected_cars=hotspot.rejected_cars,
        bailed_cars=hotspot.bailed_cars,
        count_queue_per_hour_and_avg = []))  # How can i add cars per hour here and then divide by 24?
```

So this works fine for now, but I wanna be able to sum queue lengths from  hour 1 to 24 in the last variable "count_queue_per_hour_and_avg" list.

Is this possible? How can I do it? And if not, what is your suggestions?

Underneath you can see how it is printed in terminal:

```
hotspot_day_info(hour=24, name='station1', cars_in_queue=20, rejected_cars=7076, bailed_cars=704, count_queue_per_hour_and_avg=[])
----------------------
hotspot_day_info(hour=24, name='station2', cars_in_queue=10, rejected_cars=2258, bailed_cars=606, count_queue_per_hour_and_avg=[])
----------------------
hotspot_day_info(hour=24, name='station3', cars_in_queue=20, rejected_cars=3408, bailed_cars=309, count_queue_per_hour_and_avg=[])
----------------------
hotspot_day_info(hour=24, name='station4', cars_in_queue=20, rejected_cars=5100, bailed_cars=603, count_queue_per_hour_and_avg=[])
===============================================
```

So you see at the end of each line the list is empty. But I am asking again
IS it possible to att the "cars_in_queue" values into that and sum all and in the end divide by 24 to find the average queue length for each station?

Thank you.

Comment: You realize, `hotspot_record` is a *class* correct? why are you creating a bunch of them presumably in a loop?

Comment: You might want to look into using pandas - very well suited to aggregations etc. over this kind of structured data

Comment: Will, thank you so much!

Comment: @giroud13 because you create *several equivalent but distinct classes*, and keep re-assigning to `hotspot_record` in a loop, when you should only create *one class* outside the loop. `namedtuple` is a *class factory*, which returns a new tuple-derived class, which you then re-use in the loop when you *create instances of that class*. This seems to me like you fundamentally misunderstand how to use the `namedtuple` class factory

Comment: Ok thats fine if you say so. But could you provide an example with code?

Comment: `MyRecordType = namedtuple("MyRecordType", "foo bar")`
then `foos = []`, then `for x in some_data: foos.append(MyRecordType(x.foo, x.bar)` for example, just as if you had done `class MyRecordType: ...`